# What does the error "Uncaught TypeError: mixin is not a function" mean?

Tags: magento2, requirejs

I'm trying to write a Magento Requirejs Mixin, but I'm getting the error "mixin is not a function."  What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you see the error "mixin is not a function", it should be following behind another JavaScript error such as "Unexpected identifier."

This error occurs when the requirejs mixin contains errors.

Comment: you advise is correct , I tried to add a try catch and I was able to log the root error